# How to exit for loop's NSTimer in iOS if they call in past and will show data some delay?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, for-loop, nstimer

I want to exit for loop or want to give `NSTimerIntervalvalue: 0.0` , I know it is possible

Some people will say

```
[time invalidate];
timer = nil;
```

but Let me explain with code what I want to do and what my exact problem is?

Here is my Code:

```
 -(void)loop{
     For(int i = 0 , i<=10, i++){
     timer_readtext2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:i*0.4574 invocation:invocation repeats:NO];
 }

 -(void)SomemethodwhichTimerIsCalling_i_Times{ // Assume calling invocation:invocation method
      NSLog(@"i is: %d, i");
 }
```

In this case `[time invalidate];` And `timer = nil;` is not working because method got called and loop run already and it is print the i at a certain time of delay.

I just want to stop print of i on a button click, means either loop will break or exit / timer will stop/ pause. And it will exit the method `-(void)SomemethodwhichTimerIsCalling_i_Times()`

I am not able to stop the loop or stop the timer on a button click I made some experiment and i got succeeded but when I click method `-(void)loop()` again then it will calling old and new i value again.

Any idea or suggestions would be highly welcome.

Comment: That's not real code. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes Sir This is not real code but in real code the purpose exactly the same. If I type real method here and in that method I print something like i rest all the things comment then that method will become my this method which I typed here. So my main problem is how to stop timer or exit the loop once it got run. Please have a look at my code above.

Comment: nstimer scheduledtimerWithTimeInterval repeat:YES keep instance var NSUInteger your increment each call on your timer method and on 10 in the called method invalidate your NSTimer. you can pass your NSTimer to the method called by it @selector(myMethod:) -myMethod:(NSTimer *)timer

Answer (score 1):

Actually to stop timer invocation method by just call.

```
[timer_readtext2 invalidate];
```

But this loop method should be..

```
-(void)loop{
//for(int i = 0 , i<=10, i++)// No need
timer_readtext2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:i*0.4574 invocation:invocation repeats:YES];
 }
```

When you create as NSTimer, it will start to invoke that method periodically. So you have to stop at certain time by `invalidate`.

**Update:**

```
-(void)SomemethodwhichTimerIsCalling_i_Times{ // Assume calling invocation:invocation method

     self.count +=1;
      NSLog(@"i is: %d, i",self.count);
    if (self.count > 10)
        [timer_readtext2 invalidate]
 }
```

Comment: No Sir if I do repeat yes then it will repeat untill I do something I just want the loop wil run 10 times by default and if I/ user want to stop then he can stop but without interfere it will run 10 times.

Comment: Then you can simply call 10 times in loop using `peformSelector with delay`? why do you try with NSTimer?

Comment: @Tina you would be better checking on each execution of the function to see how many times it has been run and cancel when you get to 10. Instead of setting of 10 timers.

Comment: Yes, or do what Mani said and do performSelectorWithDelay

Comment: Sir this is not the solution if I am exactly want to do I am doing already then how this problem will be solved? This is very basic thing but I got stuck means something to do here. I have to find out the solution I can change my code and can do differently but why not am I try this? Something Challenging.

Comment: @Tina My friend where you add invalidate? and inWhich condition?

Comment: @Mani In this case scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:i*0.4574, i*0.4574 time of delay not possible. I have to do this what am I trying.

Comment: @Tina What did you means? In these case, first invocation happened at 1 sec delay means, second invocation will happen at 2 sec delay(that is after 1 sec of first invocation completed). Now tell, what is your requirement?

Comment: First delay is 1*0.4574, second delay is 2*0.4574, third delay is 3*0.4574, and so on...... when till loop end.

Comment: did you means second delay(2*0.4574) from after first invocation completion or after first invocation completion, it's delay 0.4574?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating 11 timers in the loop (I hope you are aware that there will be 11 timers. "i <= 10" as the loop termination is quite unusual). Since you are creating 11 timers, invalidating *one* and setting a variable to nil isn't going to work.

Create *one* repeating timer, and not with an invocation, but with a selector for a method in your class. In that class, put a variable that is counted up every time the timer fires which you initialise to 0 when you first call the timer. In your method that handles the timer, invalidate the timer and set it to nil when that variable reaches 10. Independently, invalidate the timer and set it to nil whenever the user does something so you want to stop the timer.